# Rebus: "intoxicated"

Tags: rebus

> I have got a new rebus. Try to solve this.

[image]

Comment: I'm, like, 99% sure that op is a bot trying to break a CAPTCHA.

Answer (score 8):

I’ll try this:

> **Drunk and Disorderly**

Which like most of these answers needs no real explanation.

Comment: Flagged for deletion as unexplained answer ;-)

Comment: -1:  the letters are in not disorder; they are in the right order

Answer (score 2):

Could it be

> Sloppy drunk

Since

> "Intoxicated" (another word for "drunk") is written so sloppily.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps

> <s>Staggered</s> Staggeringly intoxicated

or

> too intoxicated to walk in a straight line

Answer (score 0):

Is it

> boozed up?

Because

> it's a lighter synonym of "intoxicated" and the letters are going up.

Answer (score 0):

A word with basically the same meaning as intoxicated is

> drunk

The text appears to be staggered, undulating;

> rolling

---

Therefore, the answer to the rebus is:

> ***Rolling Drunk***

Answer (score 0):

S t r e t c h i n g . . .

> You misspelled "excitation," Andy.

Explanation:

> intoxicate anagrams to excitation, "and d".